Requesting the reopening of the Fallout lore question about the Boeing 737
This is about the closed question: “Could the Boeing 737 have plausibly existed in the "Fallout" timeline?” The stated reason for closure is that it pertains to “Game Design and Development,” which is considered off-topic.
However, I would like to bring to your attention that our community has discussed similar lore-related questions before on meta. These meta discussions have led to a consensus that such questions are on-topic:

When is it appropriate to close a lore question as "not addressed directly through in-universe sources"?
Do we close plot-explanation questions if the answer is 'there is no explanation'?
Is "This question requires developer only knowledge" the same thing as developer intent?
Should lore questions as an entire category be banned?

As per the above meta discussion posts, I kindly request that the question be reopened.

Agreed. As I mentioned in a comment on the post - lore questions are considered on topic, even when an in-universe explanation doesn't exist. I've voted to reopen it as the third (and binding) vote.
